# Delimited Vertical Bar in SQL Table to another colum table

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, ssis, delimited

I have table data textstring using separator '|'

[image]

I've tried using SSIS to export to excel file and import again using SSIS to remove "|" and add to each column. like this

[image]

But I was just wondering if any clue how to delimit to each column without export and import? Using query SQL?

Because my data rows more than 1000 I tried using this query.

```
 SELECT 
     REVERSE(PARSENAME(REPLACE(REVERSE(DataTextRaw), ',', '.'), 1)) AS [Num]
   , REVERSE(PARSENAME(REPLACE(REVERSE(DataTextRaw), ',', '.'), 2)) AS [Index]
   , REVERSE(PARSENAME(REPLACE(REVERSE(DataTextRaw), ',', '.'), 3)) AS [Value]
FROM dbo.RAW;
```

but because my data rows more than 1000 I think this query not okay.

Comment: The best thing is to start storing your data correctly, instead of delimited - that defeats the purpose of a relational database. BTW 1000 rows is *nothing* to SQL Server...

Comment: Well [parsename()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/parsename-transact-sql) seems like a bit of a hack and is limited to four segments (three pipe delimiters in your case). If you're on a modern version of SQL Server you could probably use [string_split()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql) and [pivot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot) the resulting rows into the required columns.

Comment: One could be curious why, when you were originally importing this data in from a file, you didn't use appropriate field delimiters to split it into columns at that time.

Comment: @alwaysLearning i got this data  from read only table, so i dont have any access to file,  i need to export data to excel using ssis and import again.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `string_split()`

```
select s.*
from t cross apply
     (select max(case when seqnum = 1 then value end) as num,
             max(case when seqnum = 2 then value end) as index,
             max(case when seqnum = 3 then value end) as year,
             max(case when seqnum = 4 then value end) as curr,
             max(case when seqnum = 5 then value end) as val
      from (select s.value,
                   row_number() over (order by charindex('|' + s.value + '|', '|' + t.datatextraw + '|') as seqnum
            from string_split(t.datatextraw, '|') s
           ) s
      ) s;
```

Rumor has it that you can use `order by (select null)` instead of the strange `charindex()` expression because the latest versions of SQL Server return the values in order.  However, until the documentation changes, I won't recommend that approach.

Comment: Seem like that charindex could mix up the desired row_number effect if values from two columns are the same but are a few columns apart.

Comment: @vhoang . . . Sadly, that is true.  SQL Server does not have a documented solution for that, unless some other mechanism is used.  As I mention in the answer, an *undocumented* feature is that you can use `order by (select null)`.  But that is **undocumented**.